# Javascript function not displaying random message

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, function

Sorry my formatting sucks. I want this to display a random quote every time i click the button and a different one every time I click it. Do I need to add a document.write or some such anywhere? I'm sure there is a bunch of errors here and there but I just want to to return a random quote from the function.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Random quote</title>

    <style>

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #28315C;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    border-color: #000;
    background-color: #88D0FE;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;



}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

    var quotes = ['this is fortune 1',
                   'this is fortune 2',
                   'this is fortune 3',
                   'this is fortune 4',
                   'this is fortune 5',
                   'this is fortune 6',
                   'this is fortune 7', 
                  ];


        function newQuote(){

        var randomNumber = Math.floor(math.random() * (quotes.length));

        document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];


}

    </script>


</body>

    <div id="quoteDisplay"> 
    </div>
    <button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>


</html>
```

Comment: change `Math.floor(math.random()` to `Math.floor(Math.random()`

Comment: Step 1 in debugging - browsers **developer** tools console (F12) - your problem is that `math` !== `Math`

Answer (score 0):

In first, change `math` to `Math`. Also if you want to set only text content, then you could use `innerText` property instead of `innerHTML`. Run the snippet below.

```html
<script>
  var quotes = ['this is fortune 1',
    'this is fortune 2',
    'this is fortune 3',
    'this is fortune 4',
    'this is fortune 5',
    'this is fortune 6',
    'this is fortune 7',
  ];

  function newQuote() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerText = quotes[randomNumber];
  }
</script>

<div id="quoteDisplay">
</div>
<button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

On line 45 you typed Math with a lower case M. Change this line:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(math.random() * (quotes.length));
```

to:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
```